# ajax response returned incorrectly on live server

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-4

I'm having problems with ajax responses on my live server which all appear to work on my local server.

I'm making the request as follows:

```
$.ajax(
    {
        url : formURL,
        type: "POST",
        data : postData,
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
        {
            console.log("ajax response:", data);
                //DO SOME STUFF

            },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
        {
            console.log("Error", errorThrown);
            //if fails      
        }
});
```

In the live server I can see the response correctly in the network panel in Chrome and all looks ok. However console shows nothing at all and fails to act on the success. I can see no errors in console.

If I remove `dataType: "json"` I can see the messages in console but the data that should be displayed is poorly formatted as:

```
array() array() array('result': true)
```

I can't see where the additional arrays are coming from.

On my test server everything shows correctly in the browser and in console. With or without `dataType`

The response is coming from PHP created in laravel 4.2 on php 5.5. This is on https request rather than http. I don't know if that makes a difference?

My php is:

```
$formMessage = array(
            'result' => true,
            'title' => 'Thank you for your email',
            'message' => '<p>Thank you for your Message. We will contact you shortly (during normal business hours) to respond to your enquiry.
            </p>'
        );

        return Response::json($formMessage);
```

Are there any configurations in either php, jquery or laravel 4.2 that I'm missing that would affect this behaviour?

Text shown in chrome console for the response (being displayed by `console.log()`)

```
ajax response: Array
(
)
Array
(
)
{"result":true,"title":"Thank you for your email","message":"<p>Thank you    for your Message. We will contact you shortly (during normal business hours) to respond to your enquiry.<\/p><p>"}
```

This is with NO `dataType`

Thanks

Comment: Add to the `$.ajax` the `error` property. Something like `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) { console.log(textStatus); }` and check if there's anything on the console. It might have to do with the `dataType` property. Also, you're missing closing quote on the PHP array, check if that's a typo in the question or if you have an error there.

Comment: I do have an error part - left it out for brevity but added back in as above now. Also the typo in the post. No errors being posted in the error - it's receiving a correct response from the server but handling it poorly

Comment: Looks to me as if you have two leftover `print_r` calls in your PHP code. The result of those calls is being printed in your response and therefore corrupting the JSON string so it can't be parsed by jQuery.

Comment: Hi - sadly not - no print_r in the php code. I'm doing some tests now as I think it has something to do with the https although not sure.

Comment: I think resolved for now. I tidied up the script references and form action to ensure all going to https and it now appears to be working. NOt 100% convinced that was the soliution but it's working as expected now. Thanks